# Htaccess 301 Folder Redirection

Tags: redirect

This question has been asked before over a million times but it doesn't clear up!

I have a structure like below:

```
http://example.com/category1/subcat2/stuff3<br>
http://example.com/category4/subcat5/stuff6<br>
http://example.com/category7/subcat8/stuff9
```

I want to redirect em to the following respectively:

```
http://example.com/folder/category11/subcat22/stuff33<br>
http://example.com/folder/category44/subcat55/stuff66<br>
http://example.com/folder/category77/subcat88/stuff99
```

Notice the added folder and ALL folders and subfolders have changed names!

Furthermore there are over 2000 redirects that I need to manually place. Obviously I can't put them all in root .htaccess since 2000+ lines would slow the entire site down!

I want to break the .htaccess into the smallest bits possible i.e the stuff folders so .htaccess is individual for every redirect.

Comment: Each folder on the file system has its own .htaccess file.  You can use those.  (I'm assuming you're using apache.)

Comment: I'm aware of that but I'm not sure about the links.. Yes I'm using Apache..

Comment: `RewriteRule ^category1/(*.)/(*.)$ folder/category11/$1/$2 [L, R=301]` Not sure if this can work for you.